# T4MVC: Empty link on shared view when controller is in an area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, actionlink, t4mvc, html.actionlink

I have a shared view which contains a link to an action on a top-level controller.

I render this view from two controllers: one is in an area, and the other isn't.

When the following is rendered after being called from the controller inside the area, it's empty.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Forgotten your password?", MVC.Login.Index())
```

However, when it's called from the controller which *isn't* in the area then it populates the link correctly.

And just to be clear, the link which should be generated, "login/index", is *not* in an area.

I've tried adding

```
new { Area = "" }
```

to the `ActionLink` call but this doesn't help.

I believe that either T4MVC is trying to find a `Login.Index` action within the area, or it's passing the correct information to `ActionLink` which is then doing something I didn't expect.

So how do I instruct T4MVC or `ActionLink` to render a link to the top-level controller/action?

---

**UPDATE:**

I've found that even if I don't use T4MVC and write out the `ActionLink` call like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Forgotten your password?", "index", "login", new { Area = "" })
```

then it still renders an empty link.